# Python running multiple arguments within list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I need a python script that has the following situation.
I have a list of user IDs `"ID"` that need their respective `"names"` and `"sections"` to be updated in a loop.
I labelled them as

```
ID = ["user-19533", "user-19532", "user-19531"]
names = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
section = ["abc","pqr","xyz"]
```

I'd like the end/output to look such that

```
user-19533 would have names = test1 , section = abc
user-19532 would have names = test2 , section = pqr
user-19531 would have names = test3 , section = xyz
```

Comment: I don't get your question completely, at the beginning your talking about arrays and the next part is about Account object - can you rephrase the question?

Comment: @collinsfm316 Please edit your question and add these descriptions in the question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` here.

*The purpose of zip() is to map the similar index of multiple containers so that they can be used just using as single entity.*

Note:

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) reference link.

```
ID = ["user-19533", "user-19532", "user-19531"]
names = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
section = ["abc","pqr","xyz"]
zipped=zip(ID,names,section)
for i,name,sec in zipped:
    print(f'{i} would have names = {name} , section = {sec}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, I understood the problem correctly:

```
>>> id = ["user-19533", "user-19532", "user-19531"]
>>> names = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
>>> section = ["abc","pqr","xyz"]
>>> for i in range(len(id)):
...     print(f'{id[i]} would have name = {names[i]}, section = {section[i]}');
...
```

The output of this would be:

```
user-19533 would have name = test1, section = abc
user-19532 would have name = test2, section = pqr
user-19531 would have name = test3, section = xyz
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the unclear question previously. Yes, this worked.